# I am creating a bar chart in iOS using TeleriKUi.framework but I got 3 linker error at run time

Tags: ios

I am creating a bar chart in iOS using TeleriKUi.framework but I got 3 linker error at run time.
I am using Xcode 5.

> Ld /Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoChart.app/DemoChart normal i386
>       cd /Users/harikant/Desktop/DemoChart
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Intermediates/DemoChart.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoChart.build/Objects-normal/i386/DemoChart.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework GameKit -framework TelerikUI -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Intermediates/DemoChart.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoChart.build/Objects-normal/i386/DemoChart_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/harikant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoChart-dhiujvurrxcrawfzlfqevsxfnlkg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoChart.app/DemoChart
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBlurEffect", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TelerikUI(SideDrawerSlideInOnTop.o)
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIVisualEffectView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TelerikUI(SideDrawerSlideInOnTop.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the UIKit framework in your project? Usually when you get a 'Undefined symbols for architecture' error you can copy the method which it references and paste that into Google and see what framework it came from, if that framework was not linked in your project then just add the framework and try again. In your case '_UIBlurEffect' was not found and Google tells me that it's part of the UIKit Framework from Apple.

Comment: i am trying but din't get. any other method to build a bar chart easily in Xcode 5???